# THREE.JS displacement map not affecting shadows

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm struggling with getting the shadows working correctly with a displacement map. I've looked the problem up on Google and as far as I understand, the displacement map distorts the vertices. So in theory there shouldn't be a problem.

However, the displacement map has no effect on the shadows.
[image: image of the problem]

Answer (score 4):

Try using a custom depth material on your shadow casting sphere like so:

```js
sphere.customDepthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial( {
    depthPacking: THREE.RGBADepthPacking,
    displacementMap: displacementMap,
    displacementScale: displacementScale,
    displacementBias: displacementBias

});
```